# JSON - How to access unnamed attributes [conversion from xml]

Tags: json, xml

What is the JSON equivalent to:

```
<attributes>
    <attribute name="ISSO">SOMETHING</attribute>
    <attribute name="ALTISSO">SOMETHING</attribute>
    <attribute name="SSPDate">SOMETHING</attribute>
    <attribute name="DueDate">SOMETHING</attribute>
    <attribute name="Completed">SOMEHING</attribute>
    <attribute name="Notes">SOME NOTES</attribute>
</attributes>
```

I understand that it starts as

```
"attributes": { 
    "attribute": [ 
         { "name": "ISSO" , ???? }, 
         {"name": "ALTISSO", ???}, 
         { "name": "SSPDate", ???? } 
    ] 
};
```

What I'm not understanding is how to access the "SOMETHING" portion in JSON. I've tried #text and text and _text and __text.

The XML schema is AnyChart

Comment: There isn't a standard JSON equivalent to an arbitrary lump of XML. There are lots of different ways the data could be expressed.

Comment: incredibly helpful...

Comment: Your question isn't answerable. It isn't even clear. Your either asking how to access some data which doesn't appear in the JSON you've quoted, or your asking how you should go about expressing some data in JSON which is very much a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a FAQ Article on this topic at http://support.anychart.com/customer/portal/articles/1246584%E2%80%94anychart-6-x-how-to-insert-point-custom-attributes-when-data-is-in-json-format-

```html
{'series': 
  {'name': 'Series 1', 
    'point': [
      {'y': 1052, 'name': 'Point A', 
        attributes: {
          attribute: [
          {name: "attr1", custom_attribute_value: "val1"},
          {name: "attr2", custom_attribute_value: "val2"}
        ]}}
    ]
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't mention which platform or programming language you wanted to access it. But here's sample using Visual Studio and C#:

First, I generated the JSON from the sample XML using this site: http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.VfBX5xFViko

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "attribute": [
      {
        "name": "ISSO",
        "text": "SOMETHING"
      },
      {
        "name": "ALTISSO",
        "text": "SOMETHING"
      },
      {
        "name": "SSPDate",
        "text": "SOMETHING"
      },
      {
        "name": "DueDate",
        "text": "SOMETHING"
      },
      {
        "name": "Completed",
        "text": "SOMEHING"
      },
      {
        "name": "Notes",
        "text": "SOME NOTES"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, Pasted this to VS and generated the classes to deserialize:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    public Attribute[] attribute { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

and used Newtonsoft JSON library to deserialize

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
    var attributes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(attributes.attributes.attribute[0].text);
    // Displays SOMETHING
}
```